# could i get access to the loaded uri in actionscript for "loadmovie"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, moviecliploader

i wanna load a movieclip inside another movieclip with loadmovie or anything like this. so my question is.... could have i access to the location of the loaded swf-file inside the loaded swf-file?

example:

swf#1 loads swf#2 inside itself, so now the swf#2 should check its own uri with an identical key.. but without access to the loaded uri... it would be hard to pass this step :-). is there any information given?

as2, as3 dosn't matter.... could use both :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question in full, but any swf can get its URL, the URL it was loaded from. In AS2 it would be like this._url and in AS3 like this.loaderInfo.url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the question is asking, but can't you have swf1 pass the uri to swf2?

Comment: i need the loaded uri of swf#2 in swf#2 ... so i could get sure when the swf#2 gets loaded... if its real the requested - or needed swf#2 and not another "user edited" thing :-).... thanks a lot guys!